# PHP $_POST and id only, no name

Tags: php

Can someone please explain this to me?

I have the following code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="testField" />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
<br /><br />
<pre>
 <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

This works fine on my main dev box, and on the server.  However, I'm having to work remotely on my laptop at the moment.  I've installed the exact same WAMPServer 2.1a build as on my dev setup, and the $_POST array is empty.

If I declare the field like:

```
<input type="text" name="testField" />
```

I get the expected output.

Comment: Off the point, but you should be aware that this creates an XSS vulnerability: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`. Instead use `<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the HTML 4.01 specification, §17.2, ["Controls"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2):

> A control's "control name" is given by its name attribute.
>
> ...
>
> When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their name paired with their current value and these pairs are submitted with the form.

"id" does not matter.

Answer (score 8):

Standard behavior. Always use `name` within form.

Comment: Indeed. I'm surprised about the behaviour on the dev box. "It works fine" seems completely contrary to common sense, and to usual behaviour of HTML forms.

Comment: This is the case. It may be that the browser on your main dev box automagically uses the `id` as the missing `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You never can pass a value to another page using the id, the only attribute that php can read via methos POST is using the name of the object.

Answer (score 0):

That suggest you create a textfield that you populate with the id from the drop down list whenever changed. When you post the form the textbox will show the previous id of the drop down list. You can set the textfield to hidden